# How can I prevent users from using fake emails, which is causing my mail server to fail?

Tags: java, email, sendgrid, email-bounces

I'm using SendGrid to send registration emails to users, our users are using fake emails to register. Users cannot access the website which is goof protection for our site. But, when SendGrid tries to send them the email it bounces.

Unfortunately, we are facing more than 20-30% of fake emails on daily basis, which might lead to SendGrid blocking us altogether. What's the solution programmatically or web perspective?

**Disclaimer:** I know this is not a programming question, but not sure where should I ask it.

Comment: If you're not sure where to ask a question, you can ask for a site recommendation on Meta.SE for guidance.

Comment: So getting blocked is all you are afraid of, then ask sendgrid on their policies on this.

Comment: ServerFault might be the right site for that.

Comment: Basicially Step 1 is to validate for syntactical/technical correctness of the Email Adress, e.g. your application would not try to send mails to "foo@bar" but surely to "foo@bar.com". There are also solutions available to validate Emails for blacklisted domains to prevent the attempt to send emails e.g. to "*@trash-mail.com" which are syntacticially/technicially correct but considered "fake" from a business point of view.

Comment: @weston SendGrid policy is up to 5% bounces is ok, but we are reaching more than 20% everyday. Same for most SMTP servers.

Comment: @ReneS thank you, but I'm also asking if we might need to change the user experience or the code, so not only mail server integration.

Comment: @medopal I cannot see another flow than entering data on a webpage and getting a confirmation email afterwards. You can kick it up a notch with entering the email a second time for confirmation and adding a captcha to kill the automated scripts. Additionally make clear upfront in bold words, that a fake email won't fly and you cannot get in until verified by email. Might lower the amount.

Answer (score 3):

Change the approach if possible. Ask to your users to send you an email to register themselves (i.e. an empty email) and reply to this email with their authentication information. At this point you are sure that they are the owner of the mail address (otherwise they will not receive the credentials) and that the email is not fake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply drop the incoming bounces, you do not need them. Additionally, you might want to look at Simple Email Service from Amazon instead to get rid off problems with your own mail setup.

At the end of the day, if you want to send emails, you have to live with the returns hence you have to scale your server/service to deal with it.

Comment: Bounces are dropped automatically because the user won't be able to access the content w/o verified email. But what about the mail server which is getting a lot of bounced emails?

Comment: Returns because the email does not exist are unavoidable. The mail provider has to handle that or you have change the provider. It do not know if SendGrid has the option to drop returns to an email address such as nobody@foobar.com.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do everything you can to make sure users are signing up with valid email addresses. Here's a few ways to do that:

- Force new users to validate their email address before granting them access to the site. Email addresses can be validated by sending them an email containing a link that must be clicked to validate the account.
- Use type="email" on the input field used to enter email addresses. Good browsers (like chrome) will force a simple regex match before allowing the form to submit.
- Use a regex to filter out obviously bad emails. There's a ton of email addresses regexes floating around, suggesting looking at ones used in larger open source web frameworks, such as Django.
- Mailgun provides an API to verify email addresses. It should be used intelligently (ie: dont spam it with every signup), and can catch common misspellings and even suggest typo fixes. https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-email-validation.html

Comment: You're telling OP to make new users verify their email, before sending his email to get them to verify their email?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SendGrid mailing list, you have the option to use MailboxValidator to import your list, screen for invalid emails and then update your list automatically at SendGrid.

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/how-to-import-email-list-from-sendgrid/

But if you are using SendGrid API, you could try to integrate the MailboxValidator free API (300 free validations every 30 days) into your codes before you call the SendGrid API.

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/api-single-validation

### Sample Java code for calling the API

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String key = "Enter_License_Key";
            Hashtable<String, String> data = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            data.put("format", "json");
            data.put("email", "Enter_Email");

            String datastr = "";
            for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                datastr += "&" + entry.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");
            }
            URL url = new URL("https://api.mailboxvalidator.com/v1/validation/single?key=" + key + datastr);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```